# lodash pick: set default value if key not set

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have the following two arrays:

```js
var header = [{"user":"test"},{"name":"dummy"},{"age":0},{"address":""}];

var resultsArr = [
    { user:"test1", name: "test1", age: 23, unrelatedKey: "hello" },
    { user:"test2", name: "test2", surname: "test12" }
]
```

I'd like to clean up resultsArr such that it only has the keys found in **header** with their default values. The resultant output should look like this.

```js
[
    { user:"test1", name: "test1", age: 23, address: "" },
    { user:"test2", name: "test2", age: 0, address: "" },
]
```

I want to use it in the following code:

```js
var result = resultsArr.map(function(obj) {
  return _(obj)
    .pick(Object.keys(header))
    .defaults(defaultsObj)
    .value();
});
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: header is an array. You cannot use Object.keys on it. Try looping through header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess everything is clear from code below

```
const header = [{"user":"test"},{"name":"dummy"},{"age":0},{"address":""}];

const resultsArr = [
    { user:"test1", name: "test1", age: 23, unrelatedKey: "hello" },
    { user:"test2", name: "test2", surname: "test12" }
]

const headerUnited = Object.assign({}, ...header)
const keys = Object.keys(headerUnited)

const result = resultArr.map(v => 
  _.pick({...headerUnited, ...v}, keys)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array holding the keys in `header` and `map` the `resultsArr` to change the objects inside it :

```js
var header = [{
  user: "test"
}, {
  name: "dummy"
}, {
  age: 0
}, {
  address: ""
}];

var resultsArr = [{
    user: "test1",
    name: "test1",
    age: 23,
    unrelatedKey: "hello"
  },
  {
    user: "test2",
    name: "test2",
    surname: "test12"
  }
];

const keys = header.map((o) => Object.keys(o)[0]);

const result = resultsArr.map((obj) => {
  return keys.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc[curr] = obj[curr];
    return acc;
  }, {});
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var header = [{
  "user": "test"
}, {
  "name": "dummy"
}, {
  "age": 0
}, {
  "address": ""
}];

var resultsArr = [{
    user: "test1",
    name: "test1",
    age: 23,
    unrelatedKey: "hello"
  },
  {
    user: "test2",
    name: "test2",
    surname: "test12"
  }
]

const headerKeys = _.flatten(_.map(header, item => _.keys(item)));

/*
[
    { user:"test1", name: "test1", age: 23, address: "" },
    { user:"test2", name: "test2", age: 0, address: "" },
]
*/

const output = _.map(resultsArr, obj => {
  return _.map(headerKeys, item => {
    return {
      [item]: obj[item] ? obj[item] : ''
    }
  })
})

console.log(output)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could continue with your current approach, just a few more modification

```js
const header = [
  { user: "test" },
  { name: "dummy" },
  { age: 0 },
  { address: "" },
]

const resultsArr = [
  { user: "test1", name: "test1", age: 23, unrelatedKey: "hello" },
  { user: "test2", name: "test2", surname: "test12" },
]

const res = _(resultsArr)
  .map((obj) => _.pick(obj, _.flatMap(header, _.keys)))
  .map((obj) => _.defaults(obj, ...header))
  .value()

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is sound. To make it work, generate the `defaultsObj` by merging the headers objects to a single object - `const defaultsObj = _.merge({}, ...header);`

And then use the `_.keys()` of `defaultObj` to pick just the relevant elements from the original objects:

```js
var header = [{"user":"test"},{"name":"dummy"},{"age":0},{"address":""}];

var resultsArr = [
  { user:"test1", name: "test1", age: 23, unrelatedKey: "hello" },
  { user:"test2", name: "test2", surname: "test12" }
]

const defaultsObj = _.merge({}, ...header);

var result = resultsArr.map(function(obj) {
  return _(obj)
    .pick(_.keys(defaultsObj)) // use the defaultsObj keys
    .defaults(defaultsObj) // use the defaultsObj
    .value();
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```